# Errors in Castalia while importing in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

i had installed Omnet++ version 4 and also 5.I had imported castalia 3.2 and tested the simulation with radiotest.While running the simulation i am getting an error like 
" **Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "D:/MTECH/M.TECH" (in directory "D:\MTECH\M.TECH PROJECT\NEW OMNET++ FILES\Casssss\Simulations\radioTest"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**" 
     Not only in radiotest and i am also getting these types of errors for many simulation models.How to resolve it.Help me please.
     I had also changed the Environmental variables with java.I am not getting a solution.Please recommend a solution or please tell me which are the perfect versions to use castalia 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains spaces. A path for OMNeT++ simulator, projects, etc **must not contain spaces** nor special characters.

Comment: Oh ok sure..Let me try it once and let you know.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hello friend Thank you.it was cleared..I am an amateur to Omnet++..I need to create a cluster setup using castalia.Can u guide me how to use the tools and to work on it please?

Comment: First of all, look at tictoc samples in OMNeT++. The first example uses very simple node, which is extended in subsequent examples. They are useful to understand OMNeT++.